# Making meridians converge to both poles?

Tags: python, coordinate-system

```py
def transformx(lon, lat):
    x = lon*(90-lat)/90
    y = lat
    return x, y
```

What is the formula to make the meridians converge to both poles like the picture attached?

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

In my mind, the composition of (linear) functions is best interpreted in this way:

[image: 1]

Little does that matter to the programming language, so I think it's fine like this:

```
def transformx(lon, lat):
    x = lon*(90-abs(lat))/90
    y = lat
    return x, y
```